# Text not color: Why it doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have this code

```
    TextView.append(Html.fromHtml((getString(R.string.example))));

<string name="example"><b><font color="red">Example</font></b></string>
```

Because the text is not red when I run the app? What could be wrong?

Comment: try this first <string name="example">"<b><font color="red">Example</font></b>"</string>

Comment: you defining string value with tags in strings.xml that must be enclosed with ".

Comment: according to http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/text/Html.java#444, it should work. Both b and font (and the color attribute) are supported.

Comment: does it work if you use `color="#ff0000"`?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.example)));
```

The best way to add html source code in `strings.xml` is to use

```
<![CDATA[html source code]]>
```

Here is an example:

```
<string name="html"><![CDATA[<p>Text<p>]]></string>
```

Comment: The best way to add html source code in strings.xml is to use <![CDATA[html source code]]>. Here is an example:

<string name="html"><![CDATA[<p>Text<p>]]></string>

Comment: your comment should go in your answer.